# Difference between Shell and PHP Cron files in 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

The title pretty much sums it up. Is there a difference between the shell file and php file for the Magento cron?

If there is a difference is there a reason to run one instead of the other?

Comment: You better use cron.sh, it will check if there is any cron.php process running before call it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cron.sh is pointing to the cron.php file, so you should be pointing your cronjob task to the .sh file.

Basically inside the PHP file resides all the logic for the cron to retrieve jobs from Magento and the sh file invokes the PHP file.

Comment: The `cron.sh` file is set up to check that there isn't a cron process running in Magento before starting a new one. Always use it as the trigger. Under certain security schemes with WHM/cPanel, you may not be allowed to run shell scripts as cron jobs and only then do you directly run `cron.php` from crontab.

Comment: To add to @FiascoLabs you may have `shell_exec` disabled in WHM/cPanel, but that doesn't mean it is reported as disabled when `cron.php` checks `ini_get('disable_functions')`. So cron tries to run, sees `shell_exec` as *not* disabled, tries to use it and fails because it is disabled. *shrug*

Answer (score 7):

You should be using `cron.sh`, i.e.

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh
```

Depending on your environment, `cron.sh` runs `cron.php` which runs `cron.sh` which runs `cron.php`.  It's designed to prevent Magento's cron from executing jobs multiple times, or spawning too many processes that overlap.

---

The first time it's run, `cron.sh` will check the current running processes to see if `cron.php` is already running (without any arguments).  If not, it will execute

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/cron.php &
```

On `cron.php`s first run (and depending if your OS/host supports it) it will spawn `cron.sh` *again*, twice, but this time passing arguments:

```
/bin/sh /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh cron.php -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
/bin/sh /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh cron.php -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Back in `cron.sh` for the second time, it will check again to see if cron is running with the specified params.  If not, it will pass it back to `cron.php` with either `default` or `always`.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/cron.php -mdefault &
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/cron.php -malways &
```

And in `cron.php` for the last time, it will trigger Magento to run `default` cron jobs (pretty much all of them), as well as `always` cron jobs (like `enterprise_refresh_index`).  By separating them into two processes it reduces the risk of a long running job from blocking others.

Answer (score 5):

## cron.sh

Use `/bin/sh` to process this script

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Set a constant `CRONSCRIPT` with the file to call. $1 is the first argument, like `cron.sh /whatever/path/cron.php`

```
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi
```

set another constant, here you can pass `always` or `default` explicitly.

```
MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
    MODE=" $2"
fi
```

cron doesn't have any environment variables, therefore you can't just call `php`. `which` tells you, where the php binary is living, most likely in `/bin/php`

```
PHP_BIN=`which php`
```

`$0` is the file itself, like `__FILE__` in php

```
# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`
```

Not sure exactly how this works, but what it does: call `cron.php` with `php`.

```
#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

## cron.php

As already said, cron doesn't have a working dir or any other environment variable, therefore the working dir is set.

```
// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
```

If you call cron.php by curl or something, the filenames are fixed?

```
// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
```

Set umask, which defines with what permissions are new files created - zero permissions, no one is allowed to do anything.

```
umask(0);
```

Make sure, all functions are allowed which are needed.

```
$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

set `$cronmode`

```
try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
```

if cronmode is not set, we call `cron.sh` with both modes

```
            $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
            $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

And then magento is finally doing its job:

- load event observers and add them to the observer pool

  ```
  Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
  Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
  ```

if `shell_exec` is disabled, dispatch events, so `\Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer::dispatchAlways` and `\Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::dispatch` are running the cron tasks.

```
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```