# Why aren't product stock alerts being sent?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, ce-1.9.0.1, cron, alert

When an item comes back in stock, I expect people who are listed to receive notifications to be sent an email when the product comes back in stock, but they are not.

All other emails are being sent fine.

/cron.php is being called once every 15 minutes via crontab using curl.  I have also visited it manually in my browser.

The settings in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Alerts` Run Settings seem good, set to Daily at 15:00:00, with myself as an error contact. I don't get an error email. I've tried numerous time values for this, including +1/-1 hour from current time in case of system time discrepancies.

My `cron_schedule` database table is also empty.

Anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

If your `cron_schedule` table is empty, stock alerts (along with other features) won't work correctly.

Can you share your cron configuration settings?  Try changing `Generate Schedules Every` to `1` and then manually run `cron.sh` to see if the table gets populated.

Have you checked your error logs in case there's an issue with the `cron.php` script?  Try adding this to the beginning of the file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And run manually to see if any errors are displayed.

[Also note that you should be using `cron.sh` in the crontab](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/60282/2190), not `cron.php`.  Every 15 minutes doesn't seem frequent enough either.  I always configure it to run every minute.

Answer (score 0):

**

Product Alerts allow sending notifications on restocked products and items with price changes via customers' emails quickly. However, if you're facing an issue with product stock alerts or the alerts isn't working or fail to send an email, you can follow the below steps to fix the issue,

The notification alerts are available only for logged-in customers in the admin panel. In order to enable out-of-stock notification, you will have to change the following configuration,

1)

- **Store** > **Configuration** > Catalog > **Catalog**
- **Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock** to **Yes**

2. 

- Now, **navigate** to **Store** > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > **Inventory**
- Then, select **Display Out of Stock Products** to **Yes**
- Lastly, **save** the configuration.

**Note:** You'll receive a notification as below on saving the configuration.
"One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running."

- Now, run **Re-index** using the below command,

> php bin/magento  index:reindex

- Then, In the **core_config_data** table, change the configuration,

> crontab/default/jobs/catalog_product_alert/schedule/cron_expr

- Next, navigate to **Store** > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > Catalog > **Product
  Alerts Run Settings.**
- Now, **set** the **close** time as per your **timezone**; e.g., If it's **8 AM,**
  then **set** 8:02 AM.
- Lastly, **run** the command below in the **root folder** to run the **cron**
  without **setting** the cron.

> php bin/magento cron:run

**Clear the Cache from Cache Management:**

You must try to clear your Magento cache,

- Firstly, log in to your **Magento Admin.**
- Then, navigate to **System** > **Cache management** > **Flush Magento cache.**

Thus, I hope the above ways help you to fix the product stock alert not sending emails issue. However, if the issue persists, you can update it here.

---

**Regards,**

Rex Maughan